# How to use React Material-UI with an ASP.net MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, npm, nuget, material-ui

I am trying to use material ui for react , however this library can only be used with node package manager (npm) , my ASP.net MVC 4 project uses Nuget as a package manager so there is no way to add npm modules or even use them within js file

I need a solution to be able to add Material UI npm package to my project , is it possible to do so ? to combine both nuget and npm to manage my package

Nuget package are too limited and all the useful stuff need npm or yarn to be installed

It would be really helpful if i find a detailed guide or steps to make this work

latest nuget package of react js is  14 
i tried npm install @material-ui/core
but i cant even install the module because i dont have a packages.json file and my project does not recognize the materiel modules so i cant also use improrts within JSX nor JS files

Answer (score 0):

You install the node modules package in your ClientApp (or whatever directory your React app lives) that should be located on the same level as the controllers. This directory will function as it's own closed off react application, which have to be hooked up to the ASP.NET solution.

Microsoft has a template for creating ASP.NET web applications with React which you can check out.

You use nuget to handle dependencies in your solution and then npm to handle the node modules directory.